# Converting a do-while loop into a for loop in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

So I had this while loop for a lab in my class I had to make. I then had to convert the loop to a do-while loop to see the difference in design and make sure I got the same results. Now I need to convert it into a for loop, but I don't know how to set up the for statement. Here is how it is currently:

```
  do
  {
     die1Value = generator.nextInt(6) + 1;
     die2Value = generator.nextInt(6) + 1;
     if (die1Value == die2Value)
     {
        if (die1Value == 1)
        {   
           snakeEyes += 1;
        }
        else if (die1Value == 2)
        {   
           twos += 1;
        }   
        else if (die1Value == 3)
        {   
           threes += 1;
        }   
        else if (die1Value == 4)
        {   
           fours += 1;
        }   
        else if (die1Value == 5)
        {   
           fives += 1;
        }   
        else if (die1Value == 6)
        {   
           sixes += 1;   
        }
      }
      count += 1;
    }while (count < NUMBER);
```

Comment: And what have you [tried](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)?

Comment: I'd actually start with your original `while`, not your `do while`.  The reason is that a `for` loop does its check at the beginning, not the end, just like `while`.  So the original will be closer to what you want to finish with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the problem arises that the `for loop` will check the condition at the beginning of the loop, but your `do while` loop will check the condition at the end of your loop.

All that means is that with a `for loop`, you are *not* guaranteed at least one iteration. However, with a `do while` loop, you *are* guaranteed at least one.

Assuming that's not a problem, the `for loop` statement could be this:

```
for (count = 0; count < NUMBER; count++)
```

`count = 0` may need to be changed to `count = 1` or whatever `count` is originally supposed to start at.

---

However, seeing as how `count` would need to be initialized for your current code, you can just omit the initialization part in your `for loop` like so:

```
 for (; count < NUMBER; count++)
```

Comment: You can also just do `for (; count < NUMBER; count++)` if the initial value is defined *before* the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the Java Tutorials and Java Docs; you look to have a grip on the syntax and the meaning of each part of the loop so it shouldn't be too hard to figure out how to convert it once you read this.

(source)http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

The for statement provides a compact way to iterate over a range of values. Programmers often refer to it as the "for loop" because of the way in which it repeatedly loops until a particular condition is satisfied. The general form of the for statement can be expressed as follows:

```
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
    statement(s);
}
```

When using this version of the for statement, keep in mind that:

The initialization expression initializes the loop; it's executed once, as the loop begins.
When the termination expression evaluates to false, the loop terminates.
The increment expression is invoked after each iteration through the loop; it is perfectly acceptable for this expression to increment or decrement a value.

Answer (score 1):

The `do-while` loop does not check the condition on the first iteration, but a `for` loop does. Therefore, you need to make condition in for loop always `true` at the first time.

Try this:

```
for (boolean keepWorking = true; keepWorking; keepWorking = ++count < NUMBER) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Why not just `for (count = X; count < NUMBER, count ++)`? *where `X` is whatever initial value; it's not clear from the question* You could even just do `for (; count < NUMBER; count++)` if the initial value is defined *before* the loop.

Comment: @ADTC: First, you might be wrong in for loop statements. As I explained, a `for` loop check condition on the first iteration, so `count < NUMBER` may cause it terminated.